# Where can I find the environment created using eb CLI on the AWS console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, flask, ebcli

I created an environment using the eb CLI following the tutorial: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-flask.html

The application runs fine using the command 'eb open'. I expect to see the environment and the app in the AWS console. However, I can't find it.

The following link reports the same problem, but the solution provided does not work for me.
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=121201

Please help.

Comment: You might want to verify that in the AWS console that you are looking at the same region that the EB environment was created in.

Comment: Checked the region from eb cli: It shows a different region than my default one. Switching to this region shows the environment and app. It's weird though that aws picks up any region at random when envs are created from eb cli. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: The region default selection on the web isn't specific to Elastic Beanstalk. When you log into the web portal it picks the region that is geographically closest to you. So, for me, it defaults to us-west-2 because I'm in Seattle. But it will keep the last region you viewed between sessions. So, if you switch the region to us-east-1 and close your browser, it will still be set to us-east-1 when you log in again.